# Conflicting cross-version on scalac-scoverage-runtime

Tags: sbt, scoverage

I'm trying to run scoverage on a crossBuild `sbt coverage +test coverageAggregate` and i'm getting:

```
[error] Modules were resolved with conflicting cross-version suffixes in ProjectRef(uri("file:/Users/module/"), "module_name"):
[error]    org.scoverage:scalac-scoverage-runtime _2.12, _2.13
```

from what I can tell my dependencies are with `%%` , except one pure java dependecy

Comment: Shouldn't it be `sbt +coverage +test +coverageAggregate`?

Comment: Also can you share your _build.sbt_?